# How to get JavaScript hash table count?

Tags: javascript, hashtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Length of Javascript Associative Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-associative-array)

```
hash_table = {a: 131, b: 222, c:313}
```

The length method is not working of course since it will be confused with a key.

So how do I do it?

Comment: From the duplicate question, a useful answer that's not here. Use underscore's size, _.size().  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11346637/1684480

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`Object.keys` will return all the keys in the object as a list, then use length to get the length.

example:

```
Object.keys(hash_table).length
```

NOTE that this is ECMA 5 and may not be available in some browsers. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys for full document.

Comment: Would it return also inherited properties ?

Comment: Nope, it will return only own properties.

Comment: As I understand it, Object.keys is not supported in IE8 and lower, so beware...

Comment: Always supported in 2017 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 0;
for ( property in hash_table ) count++;
```

Comment: JSON is a data exchange format and has nothing to do with JavaScript, besides the name and similar syntax. JavaScript does not have "Associative Arrays", only arrays.

Comment: thanks for your feedbacK: I have edited my answer accordingly!

Comment: Still, what do you mean by "using Arrays in associative fashion"? The `length` property is only updated for numerical properties,i.e. `arr[0] = 42.`. Non-numerical properties do not update `length` and should not be used for arrays as it is just confusing.

Comment: please find more detailes here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Array "One can use the object declaration literal to create objects that behave much like associative arrays" but indeed I was wrong. I will edit my answer